# Arduino Nano Gnss Software Serial

Tags: arduino, gps, software-serial

I want to connect Arduino nano and GNSS (SIMCom’s SIM33ELA standalone GNSS module).

First I wrote a program for rx/tx, which is worked well, but now I want to use Software Serial and I got something wrong data.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
char incomingByte;   // for incoming serial data
double tbs;
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8, 9); // RX, TX
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);     
   while (!Serial) {    
  }
  mySerial.begin(115200);
  while (!mySerial) {
    
  } 
}

void loop() {
    if (mySerial.available()) {
      tbs = mySerial.read();
      incomingByte = (char)tbs;
     Serial.print(incomingByte);
    }

   /*if (Serial.available() > 0) {        
      incomingByte = Serial.read();            
      Serial.print(incomingByte);              
      }*/
        
}
```

Any Idea?

Pictures about results:

[Wrong data with Software serial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IODuL.png)

[Good data with Serial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoROh.png)

Comment: while (!mySerial) {

  }  What's with that line?  Did you see that in any of the SoftwareSerial Examples?

Comment: Yes I saw.... but no one can help me ....

Comment: What SoftwareSerial example did you see that line in?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, don't read one character into a `double` floating-point variable.  Just do this:

```
void loop()
{
  if (mySerial.available()) {
    char c = mySerial.read();
    Serial.write( c );
  }
}
```

You should also use AltSoftSerial on those two pins.  SoftwareSerial is very inefficient, because it disables interrupts for long periods of time.  It cannot transmit and receive at the same time.  In fact, the Arduino can do nothing else while a character is transmitted *or* received.

For a GPS library, you could try [NeoGPS](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS).  It's the only Arduino library that can parse the sentences from the newest devices.  It's also smaller, faster, more reliable and more accurate than all other libraries.